# How to intersect an array based on key values while preserving sibling key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, the first is a list of users I want to show in a web page, the second array includes a full list of users plus some data associated with each user.

I can easily reduce the list of users in the second array using the first as the master list with the `array_intersect_key()` php function, however this also removes the properties associated with each user which are needed in the web page.

How can i restrict the second list and also preserve the key value pairs of each user?

```php
$usersToShow = Array (
    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [resourcesCode] => 1/ADS
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [resourcesCode] => 1/AI
        )
    )
)
```

```
$userArray = Array(
    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [resourcesUuid] => 5B065639CEF911E3B45500505681619D
            [resourcesTimestampModified] => 1445523359
            [resourcesRecordVersionNumber] => 151
            [resourcesCode] => 1/ADS
            [resourcesName] => Ads de Sps
        )
        [1] => Array
        (
            [resourcesUuid] => 09D63BA70B045595B94B1663B4914162
            [resourcesTimestampModified] => 1434377814
            [resourcesRecordVersionNumber] => 3
            [resourcesCode] => 1/AH
            [resourcesName] => Alan Hastings
        )
        [2] => Array
        (
            [resourcesUuid] => 423C078A974F42654550E92C94EB3C5B
            [resourcesTimestampModified] => 1472547682
            [resourcesRecordVersionNumber] => 2
            [resourcesCode] => 1/AI
            [resourcesName] => Adam Iley
        )
    )
)
```

Desired result

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [resourcesCode] => 1/ADS
            [resourcesName] => Ads de Sps
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [resourcesCode] => 1/AI
            [resourcesName] => Adam Iley
        )
    )
)
```

Notes:
- the second array actually includes 100's of users, I show three here for brevity.

Comment: Just switch the order of arguments in `array_intersect_key()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to produce an output array that only contains values from `$userArray` whose `resourcesCode` value exists in `$usersToShow`:

```
$resourcesToShow = array_column($usersToShow['data'], 'resourcesCode');
$users = array();
$users['data'] = array_filter($userArray['data'], function ($v) use ($resourcesToShow) { return in_array($v['resourcesCode'], $resourcesToShow); });
print_r($users);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [resourcesUuid] => 5B065639CEF911E3B45500505681619D
                    [resourcesTimestampModified] => 1445523359
                    [resourcesRecordVersionNumber] => 151
                    [resourcesCode] => 1/ADS
                    [resourcesName] => AdsdeSps
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [resourcesUuid] => 423C078A974F42654550E92C94EB3C5B
                    [resourcesTimestampModified] => 1472547682
                    [resourcesRecordVersionNumber] => 2
                    [resourcesCode] => 1/AI
                    [resourcesName] => AdamIley
                )

        )

)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TCZOo)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `array_map()` and `array_filter()`. `array_map()` is for extracting the match data from `$userArray` and `array_filter()` is for removing the values which are not match with `$usersToShow`.

```
$filter = array_column($usersToShow['data'], 'resourcesCode');
$result = array_filter(array_map(function($value) use ($filter) {
    return in_array($value['resourcesCode'], $filter)
        ? [
            'resourcesCode' => $value['resourcesCode'],
            'resourcesName' => $value['resourcesName']
        ] : null;
}, $userArray['data']));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/mXT90).